# Prim's algorithm when range of Edge weights is known

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

**Suppose that all the edge weights in a graph are integers in the range from 1 to |V|. How fast can you make Prim's algorithm run? What if edge weights are integers in the range 1 to W for some constant W?**

I think since the Prim's algorithm is based on implementation of min-heap, knowledge about the weights of edges will not help in speeding up the procedure. Is this correct?

Comment: Try the van Emde Boas tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree

You can get log log V/W like this

Answer (score 0):

With this constraint, you can implement a heap that uses `O(V)` / `O(W)` respectively space but has `O(1)` insert and `O(1)` extract-min operations. Actually you can get `O(1)` for all operations you require for Prim's algorithm. Since the time complexity of the heap influences the complexity of the main algorithm, you can get better than the default generic implementation.

Comment: are you suggesting using a priority queue? and if so, how can i perform the operations in O(1) as you have pointed out. For eg. if I include a vertex into the mst, and I have to update all the key values for the other vertices in the queue (similar to the decrease key operation in the heap). How will I do it in O(1)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main idea to solve this problem is remember that **W** is a constant, so, if you represent your priority queue as some structure which size is bounded by **W**, travel the entire list at each iteration will not change the time complexity of your algorithm...

For example, if you represent your priority queue as an array **T** with **W + 1** positions, having a linked list of vertices in each position such that **T[i]** is a list with all the vertices that have priority equal to **i** and use **T[W + 1]** to store vertices with priority equal to infinite, you will take

**O(V)** to build your priority queue (just insert all the vertices in the list **T[W+1]**)

**O(W)** to *extract the minimum element* (just travel **T** searching for the first position non empty)

**O(1)** to decrease key (if vertex **v** had key equal to **i** and it was updated to **j**, just take-off **v** from list **T[i]** and insert at the first position of the list **T[j]**).

So, it will give you complexity **O(VW + E)** instead of **O(V logV + E)**.

(Of course, it will not work if the range is from 1 to **V**, because **V^2 + E** is greater than **V \logV + E**).

Comment: I don't quite see how decrease key is O(1)? You'd have to walk all the way down list T[i] in the worst case, which can have up to V elements.

Answer (score 0):

For non-binary heap Prim's implementation, the pseudocode can be found with Cormen, Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition.

Knowing the range being 1...k, we can create an array with k size and walk through the list, adding edges to the corresponding weight. This, by nature of its storage, means the edges are sorted by weights. This would be O(n+m) time.

Relying on the pseudocode for Prim's algorithm in Cormen, we can analyze its complexity to result in O(nlog{n} + mlog{n}) = O((n+m)log{n}) time (Cormen page 636). In specific, step 7 and step 11 contributes the log{n} element that is iterated over n and m loop. The n log{n}-loop is from the EXTRACT-MIN operation, and the m log{n}-loop is from the "implicit DECREASE-KEY" operation. Both can be replaced with our edge-weight array, a loop of O(k). As such, with our modified Prim's algorithm, we would have a O(nk + mk) = O(k(n+m)) algorithm.